# CSS reset overriden background color

Tags: css, background-color, adminlte

I'm using AdminLTE 2.3.8. It overrides buttons background on it's box header buttons when hovered, but I want to keep original colors when hovered over any buttons. Eg.:

**AdminLTE CSS:**

```
.btn-default {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.box.box-solid>.box-header .btn.btn-default {
    background: transparent;
}
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.hover {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.box.box-solid>.box-header .btn:hover,
.box.box-solid>.box-header a:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

I just want to get rid of these `.box.box-solid>...` rules without editing vendor's CSS. Is there any way to achieve this without copying every button style (there are different colors)? If there is, solution would be very welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Use `!important` within your styles, so that any other vendor styles doesn't conflict with these buttons.

Example:

```
.btn.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question if it's event possible to reset just some styles without overriding each button color (plus hover colors).